# very simple app tab iframe - won't load

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I created the simplest app ever - I basically just want to iframe my website paleoitforward.com.

[>> Here is a screenshot of my app settings](http://heathercash.com/facebook/fb-ss1.png)

However, I get an error message on the page. You can see it in action here:
http://facebook.com/heathercashart/app_337591392998654

In Chrome, I get the message "This webpage is not available"
In Firefox, I get the message "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost."

Localhost... how weird?

I can't figure out why it won't load, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it :-/

The site loads over HTTPS fine, so HTTPS is not the problem.

Also - FYI - I am a n00b at this Facebook app stuffs... :)

Thanks,
Heather

Comment: describe the settings you entered when you setup your app.

Comment: Oh, I did attach a screenshot of my settings... but I will copy them down & write them here too... I just need a few minutes :)

Comment: Ok, here they are:


Display Name: Paleo It Forward
Namespace: paleoitforward
Contact Email: xxxx@gmail.com
App Domains: paleoitfoward.com
Category: Health & Fitness
Hosting URL: (none)
Sandbox Mode: Disabled


Website with Facebook Login
 - Site URL: http://www.paleoitfoward.com

Page Tab
 - Page Tab Name: Paleo It Forward
 - Page Tab URL: http://www.paleoitforward.com
 - Secure Page Tab URL: https://www.paleoitforward.com
 - Page Tab Edit URL: http://www.paleoitforward.com
 - Page Tab Image (there's an image there)
 - Page Tab Width: x Narrow (520px)

Comment: Also, btw - I can't actually *attach* a screenshot b/c I don't have enough reputation points apparently - that's why I put the URLs. Also I could only put 2 linkable URLs b/c I don't have enough rep points, which is why 2 of my URLs aren't linked. Sorry for the inconvenience :(

Comment: oops sorry how did i miss that you already linked it :)

Comment: Everything looks fine. I suspect that your problem might be in fact the lack of HTTPS. Having a secure URL is a relatively new requirement and Facebook might handle the absence of such URL's differently for old apps than for new ones.

Comment: Note that the request from Facebook for a page tab app comes as a HTTP POST request, not a GET like regular pages. Check the page tab URL has a '/' at the end as many servers will redirect from 'mysite.com' to 'mysite.com/' which will break the POST request from Facebook and leave you with a broken page tab app

Comment: Whoah! Sorry, I JUST saw these comments!! Thanks so much about the paintings :) :) You were right about the slash!!! After I added the trailing slash, now I get a REAL error message - "This webpage is not available" - so that must be because of the HTTPS right? BTW - does it request the app page as HTTPS regardless of whether I am viewing the FB page at HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Hi, I got the website available over HTTPS, but am still having the problem, with the same error message :(

HTTPS: https://paleoitforward.com/
ERROR here: http://www.facebook.com/heathercashart/app_337591392998654

It says Webpage Not Available.

Could it be because when you go to my website with a trailing slash, the trailing slash is removed (in the htaccess file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app settings (the screenshot shows it) you wrote `paleoitfoward.com` in your page tab settings – missing the **R** in *foRRRRRRRRRRward* …

*Live is easier if one can read, believe you me :-)*

Comment: OMG!! That explains why randomly changing the URLs, I eventually got it to work. Sheesh :-P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am not exactly sure what fixed this, but I was basically just messing around changing the `URL`'s (adding http, removing http, adding trailing slash, removing it...) and all of a sudden it worked!

Here are the URLs I used that ended up working in case anyone has this problem in the future (make sure you pay close attention to http/https and trailing slashes!):

App domains: `paleoitforward.com`

```
Website with Facebook Login
  Site URL: http://paleoitforward.com

Page Tab
  Page Tab URL: https://paleoitforward.com
  Secure Page Tab URL: https://paleoitfoward.com/
  Page Tab Edit URL: https://paleoitfoward.com/
```

Comment: I've been having this exact same problem myself, although some people have had no problems accessing the page tab (yet other errors cropped up on them later). Removing the trailing slash from 'Page Tab URL' appears to have made it start working for me all of a sudden. I can't explain it otherwise except some mystical cloud computing or server cluster issue. Mine still has a trailing slash of the HTTPS version.